# What command can search for a specific file in my home directory?

Tags: unix

Writing a beginner shell script and it's asking for to locate and verify if a file under a specific name is located within my home directory but I'm not sure what command would best fit that.

Comment: Start with `find`. See the documentation.

Comment: OR `cd $HOME ; ls -l "$myFileName"` Please update your question with your best attempt to solve your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To find any file in linux, use this command:

```
find . -name file_name
```

point means current directory
you can change it to /home/

thanks